# Puppeter: Generating a PDF of a Vue page using Vuex store/state leads to blank pages

Tags: vue.js, pdf, vuex, puppeteer

#### Steps to reproduce

**Tell us about your environment:**

- Puppeteer version: 2.0.0
- Platform / OS version: local machine Windows 10
- URLs (if applicable): N/A
- Node.js version: v10.16.0

**What steps will reproduce the problem?**
N/A

*Please include code that reproduces the issue.*

1. for example this some code to generate the header in the invoice

```
<v-col cols="9" class="d-flex flex-column pt-3">
                    <div>
                        <span class="header-title">{{ Office__title  }}</span>
                        <span class="header-subtitle font-weight-bold" style="vertical-align: top">{{ '(' + Office__companyno + ')' }}</span>
                    </div>
                    <span class="header-subtitle pt-1 pb-0">{{ Office__address1  }}</span>
                    <span class="header-subtitle pt-1 pb-0">{{ [Office__address2, Office__city, Office__state, Office__country].join(', ')  }}</span>
                    <span class="header-subtitle pt-1 pb-0">{{ $t('message.tel') + ': ' + Office__contracttel  }}</span>
                    <span class="header-subtitle pt-1 pb-0">{{ $t('message.email') + ': ' + Office__contractemail + ' ' + $t('message.website') + ': ' + Office__website }}</span>
                </v-col>
```

2. The variables are obtained using this:

```
data() {
            return {
                appLogo: AppConfig.appSessionLogo,
                deliveryAddresses: [],
                loaded: false,
            };
        },
        computed: {
            ...mapFields('contract', {
                Contract__id: 'print.Contract.id',
                Contract__Bank_id: 'print.Contract.Bank.id',
                Contract__Bank_title: 'print.Contract.Bank.title',
                Contract__Bank_account: 'print.Contract.Bank.account',
                Contract__Bank_swiftcode: 'print.Contract.Bank.swiftcode',
                Contract__Bank_beneficiary: 'print.Contract.Bank.beneficiary',
                Contract__Deliveryaddress_address: 'print.Contract.Deliveryaddress.address',
         etc, etc....
```

Note: ...mapFields id from this package "maoberlehner/vuex-map-fields". Using standard ...mapGetters also replicates the issue.

**What is the expected result?**
PDF of the sales invoice should appear

**What happens instead?**
I get two blank pages. When I pdf.goto to another page in my site where no Vuex is used I get a render of the page.

If I pull directly from the API into the page without using Vuex the page is rendered. I would very much like to use the Vuex actions, state, mutations in the print page so I don't have to rewrite some of the code 2x. Does anyone have any experience doing this? I googled high and low and only found 1 or 2 postings but with no solution mentioned.

EDIT 2020-05-15 1:25PM
Entire Code:

```
<template>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column fill-height">
        <v-col class="pa-0 ma-0 mb-auto">
            <v-row no-gutters>
                <v-col cols="9" class="d-flex flex-column pt-3">
                    <div>
                        <span class="header-title">{{ Office__title  }}</span>
                        <span class="header-subtitle font-weight-bold" style="vertical-align: top">{{ '(' + Office__companyno + ')' }}</span>
                    </div>
                    <span class="header-subtitle pt-1 pb-0">{{ Office__address1  }}</span>
                    <span class="header-subtitle pt-1 pb-0">{{ [Office__address2, Office__city, Office__state, Office__country].join(', ')  }}</span>
                    <span class="header-subtitle pt-1 pb-0">{{ $t('message.tel') + ': ' + Office__contracttel  }}</span>
                    <span class="header-subtitle pt-1 pb-0">{{ $t('message.email') + ': ' + Office__contractemail + ' ' + $t('message.website') + ': ' + Office__website }}</span>
                </v-col>
                <v-col cols="3" class="text-right">
                    <img
                            :src="appLogo"
                            class="mb-3 mr-3"
                            width="130px"
                    />
                </v-col>
            </v-row>
            <v-row no-gutters>
                <v-col cols="12" class="text-center text-uppercase border-top-2 border-bottom-2 pa-1 font-weight-bold document-caption">{{ $t('message.contract') }}</v-col>
            </v-row>
            <v-row no-gutters>
                <v-col cols="6" class="d-flex flex-column py-0">
                    <span class="font-weight-bold">{{ Contract__sellertitle }}</span>
                    <span v-if="[1,5].includes(Contract__salestype_id)">{{ Contract__office_id != null ? offices.filter((d) => d.Office.id == Contract__office_id)[0].Office.title : null }}</span>
                    <div v-else-if="[2].includes(Contract__salestype_id)" class="d-flex flex-column">
                        <span>{{ findSupplierById(Contract__supplier_id).Supplier.title }}</span>
                        <span>{{ findSupplierById(Contract__supplier_id).Company.address1 }}</span>
                        <span>{{ findSupplierById(Contract__supplier_id).Company.address2 }}</span>
                        <span>{{ findSupplierById(Contract__supplier_id).Company.address3 }}</span>
                        <span>{{ findSupplierById(Contract__supplier_id).Company.city + ' ' + findSupplierById(Contract__supplier_id).Company.postcode }}</span>
                        <span>{{ findSupplierById(Contract__supplier_id).Country.state }}</span>
                        <span>{{ findSupplierById(Contract__supplier_id).Country.name }}</span>
                    </div>
                </v-col>
                <v-col cols="2" class="d-flex flex-column py-0">
                    <span class="font-weight-bold">{{ $t('message.marketing') }}</span>
                    <span>{{ findSalesColleagueById(Contract__salescontact_id).Salesperson.name }}</span>
                </v-col>
                <v-col cols="2" class="d-flex flex-column py-0">
                    <span class="font-weight-bold">{{ $t('message.date') }}</span>
                    <span>{{ Contract__contractdate ? formatDate(Contract__contractdate) : '' }}</span>
                </v-col>
                <v-col cols="2" class="d-flex flex-column py-0">
                    <span class="font-weight-bold text-right">{{ $t('message.number') }}</span>
                    <span class="text-right">{{ Contract__title }}</span>
                </v-col>
            </v-row>
            <v-row no-gutters class="pt-1">
                <v-col cols="6" class="d-flex flex-column py-0">
                    <span class="font-weight-bold">{{ $t(buyerCaption) }}</span>
                    <span>{{ findBuyerById(Contract__customer_id).Customer.title }}</span>
                    <span>{{ findBuyerById(Contract__customer_id).Company.address1 }}</span>
                    <span>{{ findBuyerById(Contract__customer_id).Company.address2 }}</span>
                    <span>{{ findBuyerById(Contract__customer_id).Company.address3 }}</span>
                    <span>{{ findBuyerById(Contract__customer_id).Company.city + ' ' + findBuyerById(Contract__customer_id).Company.postcode}}</span>
                    <span>{{ findBuyerById(Contract__customer_id).Company.state }}</span>
                    <span>{{ findBuyerById(Contract__customer_id).Country.name }}</span>
                </v-col>
                <v-col cols="6" class="d-flex flex-column py-0">
                    <span class="font-weight-bold">{{ $t(deliveryCaption) }}</span>
                    <span>{{ Deliveryaddress__address }}</span>
                </v-col>
            </v-row>
            <v-row no-gutters class="pt-1">
                <v-col cols="8" class="d-flex flex-column py-0">
                    <span class="font-weight-bold">{{ $t('message.termsOfPayment') }}</span>
                    <span>{{ findBuyerPaymentTermById(Contract__paymentstatement_id).Paymentterm.title }}</span>
                </v-col>
                <v-col cols="4" class="d-flex flex-column py-0">
                    <span class="font-weight-bold text-right">{{ $t('message.shipment') }}</span>
                    <span class="text-right">{{ Contract__shippingweekstatement }}</span>
                </v-col>
            </v-row>
            <v-row no-gutters class="pt-1">
                <v-col cols="6" class="d-flex flex-column py-0">
                    <span class="font-weight-bold">{{ $t('message.paidTo') }}</span>
                    <span :class="Contract__Bank_id ? '' : 'red--text'">
                        <span style="white-space: pre">{{ Contract__Bank_id ? contractBank : '' }}</span>
                    </span>
                </v-col>
                <v-col cols="6" class="d-flex flex-column py-0">
                    <span class="font-weight-bold text-right">{{ $t('message.countryOriginDestination') }}</span>
                    <span class="text-right">
                        {{ Contract__productorigin_id != null ? findCountryById(Contract__productorigin_id).Country.name : '' }} /
                        {{ Contract__destinatione_id != null ? findCountryById(Contract__destinatione_id).Country.name : '' }}
                    </span>
                    <span class="font-weight-bold text-right">{{ $t('message.termsOfDelivery') }}</span>
                    <span class="text-right">{{ contractIncoterm }}</span>
                </v-col>
            </v-row>
        </v-col>
        <v-col class="px-0 pb-0 pt-3 ma-0 mb-auto">
            <v-simple-table
                    class="specification-table"
                    dense
            >
                <template v-slot:default>
                    <tr class="table-header">
                        <td class="px-0 font-weight-bold border-bottom-1">{{ $t('message.specification') }}</td>
                        <td class="px-0 font-weight-bold border-bottom-1">{{ $t('message.size') }}</td>
                        <td class="px-0 font-weight-bold border-bottom-1">{{ $t('message.grade') }}</td>
                        <td class="px-0 font-weight-bold text-right width-10-pct border-bottom-1">{{ $t('message.quantity') }}</td>
                        <td class="px-0 font-weight-bold text-right width-10-pct border-bottom-1">{{ $t('message.unitPrice') }}</td>
                        <td class="px-0 font-weight-bold text-right width-10-pct border-bottom-1">{{ $t('message.amount') }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <template v-for="(item,index) in Salesitems">
                        <tr class="table-row-main" v-if="index == 0 ">
                            <td colspan="6">{{ item.Salesdescription.title }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="table-row" v-else-if="index > 0 && Salesitems[index - 1].Salesdescription.title != item.Salesdescription.title">
                            <td colspan="6">{{ item.Salesdescription.title }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="table-row-sub">
                            <td></td>
                            <td class="px-0">{{ item.Size.title }}</td>
                            <td class="px-0">{{ item.Grade.title }}</td>
                            <td class="px-0 text-right">{{ item.type != 'credit' ? formatThisNumber(item.Salesitem.itemqty,uofmPrecision(item.Measurement.title)) + ' ' + uofmQty.find((uofm)=>uofm.Measurement.id == item.Salesitem.measurement_id).Measurement.title : '' }}</td>
                            <td class="px-0 text-right">{{ item.type != 'credit' ? formatThisNumber(item.Salesitem.unitprice,currencyFormatPrecision) : '' }}</td>
                            <td class="px-0 text-right">{{ item.type != 'credit' ? formatThisNumber(item.Salesitem.amount,currencyFormatPrecision) : '(' + formatThisNumber(item.Salesitem.amount,currencyFormatPrecision) + ')' }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </template>
                </template>
            </v-simple-table>
        </v-col>
        <v-col class="px-0 pb-0 pt-3 ma-0 mt-auto">
            <v-simple-table
                    class="specification-table"
                    dense
            >
                <template v-slot:default>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4" class="px-0">
                            <span style="white-space: pre-line">
                                {{ Contract__note != null ? Contract__note.trim() : '' }}
                            </span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="px-0 font-weight-bold border-bottom-1">
                            <div class="d-flex flex-column">
                                <span>{{ Contract__fsc != 0 ? $t('message.certCode') + ' : ' + certifications.find((certification)=>certification.Certification.id == Contract__fsc).Certification.cert_no : '' }}</span>
                                <span>{{ Contract__fsc != 0 ? $t('message.expiryDate') + ' : ' + certifications.find((certification)=>certification.Certification.id == Contract__fsc).Certification.cert_expiry_date : '' }}</span>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="px-0 font-weight-bold text-right width-10-pct border-bottom-1">
                            <span class="text-uppercase pr-3">{{ $t('message.total') }}</span>
                            <span v-if=" [1,2,5].includes(Contract__containersize_id) ">{{ Contract__containercount }}</span>
                            <span v-if=" [1,2,5].includes(Contract__containersize_id) "> X </span>
                            <span>{{ containerSizes.find(containerSize => containerSize.Containersize.id == Contract__containersize_id).Containersize.title }}</span>
                        </td>
                        <td class="px-0 font-weight-bold text-right width-10-pct border-bottom-1">
                            <span v-for="(total,index) in itemsTotalQty">
                                    {{ formatThisNumber(total.Total.qty, uofmPrecision(total.Total.uofm)) + ' '+ total.Total.uofm }}
                            </span>
                        </td>
                        <td class="px-0 font-weight-bold text-right width-10-pct border-bottom-1">{{ currencies.find((currency) => currency.Currency.id == Contract__currency_id).Currency.code }}</td>
                        <td class="px-0 font-weight-bold text-right width-10-pct border-bottom-1">{{ formatThisNumber(itemsTotalAmount,currencyFormatPrecision) }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </template>
            </v-simple-table>
        </v-col>
        <div class="mt-auto">
            <v-row no-gutters class="pt-2">
                <v-col cols="12">{{ $t('message.notes') + ':' }}</v-col>
                <v-col cols="12" v-for="footerNote in contractFooterNotes" v-if="Contract__footernotes.includes(footerNote.id)" :key="footerNote.id">
                    <div class="d-flex flex-row align-stretch">
                        <span class="px-1">-</span>
                        <span class="footer-note text-wrap">{{ footerNote.text }}</span>
                    </div>
                </v-col>
                <v-col cols="12" v-else-if="Contract__destinatione_id == 1 && footerNote.id == 10">
                    <div class="d-flex flex-row align-stretch">
                        <span class="px-1">-</span>
                        <span class="footer-note text-wrap">{{ footerNote.text }}</span>
                    </div>
                </v-col>
            </v-row>
            <v-row no-gutters class="align-end">
                <v-col cols="7" class="d-flex flex-column py-0">
                    <span class="font-weight-bold">{{ $t('message.confirmedBySeller') }}</span>
                    <span class="stamp-area text-center pt-2">
                        <img
                                :src="'/static/img/appic/stamps/' + (Contract__stampsignatured == 1 ? Office__stamp_ws : Office__stamp)"
                                height="80px"
                                v-if="Contract__showsignature != 'N'"
                        >
                    </span>
                    <span class="font-weight-bold border-top-1">{{ $t('message.companyStamp') }}</span>
                </v-col>
                <v-col cols="5" class="d-flex flex-column py-0">
                    <span class="font-weight-bold ml-3">{{ $t('message.confirmedByBuyer') }}</span>
                    <span class="stamp-area"></span>
                    <span class="font-weight-bold border-top-1 ml-3">{{ '(' + $t('message.pleaseSign') + ')' }}</span>
                </v-col>
            </v-row>
        </div>
        <div id="loaded" v-if="loaded"></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import AppConfig from "Constants/AppConfig";
    import {mapFields, mapMultiRowFields} from "vuex-map-fields";
    import {mapActions, mapGetters} from "vuex";
    import {formatDate, numberFormat} from "../../../helpers/helpers";
    import {api} from "../../../api";

    export default {
        name: "PrintContract",
        props: ['contractId'],
        data() {
            return {
                appLogo: AppConfig.appSessionLogo,
                deliveryAddresses: [],
                loaded: false,
            };
        },
        computed: {
            ...mapFields('contract', {
                Contract__id: 'print.Contract.id',
                Contract__Bank_id: 'print.Contract.Bank.id',
                Contract__Bank_title: 'print.Contract.Bank.title',
                Contract__Bank_account: 'print.Contract.Bank.account',
                Contract__Bank_swiftcode: 'print.Contract.Bank.swiftcode',
                Contract__Bank_beneficiary: 'print.Contract.Bank.beneficiary',
                Contract__Deliveryaddress_address: 'print.Contract.Deliveryaddress.address',
                Contract__buyeraddresstype: 'print.Contract.buyeraddresstype',
                Contract__contractdate: 'print.Contract.contractdate',
                Contract__commission_per_line: 'print.Contract.commission_per_line',
                Contract__containercount: 'print.Contract.containercount',
                Contract__containersize_id: 'print.Contract.containersize_id',
                Contract__currency_id: 'print.Contract.currency_id',
                Contract__customer_id: 'print.Contract.customer_id',
                Contract__destinatione_id: 'print.Contract.destinatione_id',
                Contract__deliveryaddress_id: 'print.Contract.deliveryaddress_id',
                Contract__incoterm_id: 'print.Contract.incoterm_id',
                Contract__incotermport: 'print.Contract.incotermport',
                Contract__fsc: 'print.Contract.fsc',
                Contract__footernotes: 'print.Contract.footernotes',
                Contract__loadingport_id: 'print.Contract.loadingport_id',
                Contract__margin: 'print.Contract.margin',
                Contract__note: 'print.Contract.note',
                Contract__office_id: 'print.Contract.office_id',
                Contract__paymentstatement_id: 'print.Contract.paymentstatement_id',
                Contract__productorigin_id: 'print.Contract.productorigin_id',
                Contract__salescontact_id: 'print.Contract.salescontact_id',
                Contract__salestype_id: 'print.Contract.salestype_id',
                Contract__sellertitle: 'print.Contract.sellertitle',
                Contract__shippingport_id: 'print.Contract.shippingport_id',
                Contract__shipweekdate: 'print.Contract.shipweekdate',
                Contract__shippingweekstatement: 'print.Contract.shippingweekstatement',
                Contract__showbank: 'print.Contract.showbank',
                Contract__showsignature: 'print.Contract.showsignature',
                Contract__stampsignatured: 'print.Contract.stampsignatured',
                Contract__supplier_id: 'print.Contract.supplier_id',
                Contract__title: 'print.Contract.title',
                Deliveryaddress__address: 'print.Contract.Deliveryaddress.address',
                Office__title: 'print.Contract.Office.title',
                Office__address1: 'print.Contract.Office.address1',
                Office__address2: 'print.Contract.Office.address2',
                Office__city: 'print.Contract.Office.city',
                Office__companyno: 'print.Contract.Office.companyno',
                Office__contractemail: 'print.Contract.Office.contractemail',
                Office__contracttel: 'print.Contract.Office.contracttel',
                Office__country: 'print.Contract.Office.country',
                Office__postcode: 'print.Contract.Office.postcode',
                Office__state: 'print.Contract.Office.state',
                Office__stamp: 'print.Contract.Office.stamp',
                Office__stamp_ws: 'print.Contract.Office.stamp_ws',
                Office__website: 'print.Contract.Office.website'
            }),
            ...mapFields('salesitem',{
                itemsTotalAmount: 'print.itemsTotalAmount',
                itemsTotalQty: 'print.itemsTotalQty'
            }),
            ...mapGetters('bankaccount', {
                allBankAccounts: 'allBankAccounts',
                findBankAccountById: 'findBankAccountById',
                findBankAccountsByOfficeAndCurrency: 'findBankAccountsByOfficeAndCurrency',
            }),
            ...mapGetters('buyer', {
                allBuyers: 'allBuyers',
                findBuyerById: 'findBuyerById'
            }),
            ...mapGetters('country',{
                allCountries: 'allCountries',
                findCountryById: 'findCountryById'
            }),
            ...mapGetters('paymentterm', {
                allBuyerPaymentTerms: 'allBuyerPaymentTerms',
                findBuyerPaymentTermById: 'findBuyerPaymentTermById'
            }),
            ...mapGetters('salescolleague',{
                allSalesColleagues: 'allSalesColleagues',
                findSalesColleagueById: 'findSalesColleagueById'
            }),
            ...mapMultiRowFields('salesitem', {
                Salesitems: 'print.Salesitems',
            }),
            ...mapGetters('shippingport', {
                allShippingLoadingPorts: 'allShippingLoadingPorts',
                allShippingDischargePorts: 'allShippingDischargePorts',
                findShippingPortById: 'findShippingPortById'
            }),
            ...mapGetters('supplier', {
                allSuppliers: 'allSuppliers',
                findSupplierById: 'findSupplierById'
            }),
            ...mapGetters([
                'buyerCaptionTypes',
                'certifications',
                'containerSizes',
                'contractFooterNotes',
                'currencies',
                'deliveryAddressTypes',
                'incoterms',
                'offices',
                'uofmQty'
            ]),
            buyerCaption() {
                return this.buyerCaptionTypes.find((caption)=>caption.id == this.Contract__buyeraddresstype).title_first
            },
            contractIncoterm() {
                let incoterm = this.incoterms.find((incoterm)=>incoterm.Incoterm.id == this.Contract__incoterm_id)?.Incoterm?.title;
                let incotermport = null;
                switch(this.Contract__incotermport){
                    case 0: //POD
                        if(this.Contract__shippingport_id != null) {
                            incotermport = ' ' + this.findShippingPortById(this.Contract__shippingport_id).Shippingport.title
                        }
                        break;
                    case 1: //POL
                        if(this.Contract__loadingport_id != null) {
                            incotermport = ' ' + this.findShippingPortById(this.Contract__loadingport_id).Shippingport.title
                        }
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        return null
                        break
                }
                return incoterm + incotermport;
            },
            contractBank(){
                let bank = '';
                if(this.Contract__Bank_id != null){
                    if(this.Contract__Bank_title){ bank += this.$t('message.banker') + ': ' + this.Contract__Bank_title.trim()}
                    if(this.Contract__Bank_swiftcode){ bank += "\n" +  this.$t('message.swiftCode') + ': ' + this.Contract__Bank_swiftcode.trim()}
                    if(this.Contract__Bank_account){ bank += "\n" + this.$t('message.accountNo') + ': ' + this.Contract__Bank_account.trim()}
                    if(this.Contract__Bank_beneficiary){ bank += "\n" + this.$t('message.beneficiary') + ': ' + this.Contract__Bank_beneficiary.trim()}
                }
                return bank
            },
            currencyFormatPrecision () {
                return this.currencies.find((currency) => currency.Currency.id === this.Contract__currency_id)?.Currency?.formatPrecision
            },
            deliveryCaption() {
                return this.buyerCaptionTypes.find((caption)=>caption.id == this.Contract__buyeraddresstype).title_last
            }
        },
        methods: {
            ...mapActions('contract',{
                getContractToPrintById: 'getContractToPrintById'
            }),
            ...mapActions('bankaccount', {
                getAllBankAccounts: 'getAllBankAccounts'
            }),
            ...mapActions('buyer', {
                getAllActiveBuyers: 'getAllActiveBuyers',
                // resetAllBuyers: 'resetAllBuyers'
            }),
            ...mapActions('contract',{
                getContractToPrintById: 'getContractToPrintById',
            }),
            ...mapActions('supplier', {
                getAllSuppliers: 'getAllSuppliers',
                resetAllSuppliers: 'resetAllSuppliers'
            }),
            ...mapActions('shippingport', {
                getAllShippingPorts: 'getAllShippingPorts',
            }),
            ...mapActions('salescolleague', {
                getAllSalesColleagues: 'getAllSalesColleagues',
            }),
            ...mapActions('salesitem',{
                getSalesItemsToPrintByContract: 'getSalesItemsToPrintByContract'
            }),
            ...mapActions('paymentterm', {
                getAllPaymentTerms: 'getAllPaymentTerms',
                getAllBuyerContractPaymentTerms: 'getAllBuyerContractPaymentTerms'
            }),
            formatDate,
            formatThisNumber(value,format){
                return numberFormat(value,format)
            },
            loadContractById (val) {
                this.getContractToPrintById(val)
                    .then((contract_id)=>{
                        this.getSalesItemsToPrintByContract(contract_id)
                    })
                    .then(()=>{
                    })
            },
            uofmPrecision (uofm) {
                return this.uofmQty.find((u) => u.Measurement.title == uofm.trim()).Measurement.formatPrecision
            },
        },
        created() {
            // Testing
            // this.$store.dispatch('resetConstantsState')
            // this.resetAllBuyers() //to reset the buyer list
            // this.resetAllSuppliers() //to reset the supplier list

            if(!this.allBankAccounts.length) this.getAllBankAccounts()
            if(!this.allBuyers.length) this.getAllActiveBuyers()
            if(!this.allBuyerPaymentTerms.length) this.getAllPaymentTerms()
            if(!this.allSalesColleagues.length) this.getAllSalesColleagues()
            if(!this.allSuppliers.length) this.getAllSuppliers()
            if(!this.allShippingLoadingPorts.length) this.getAllShippingPorts()

            if(this.$route.matched.some(({name}) => name === 'print_contract')){
                this.loadContractById(this.contractId)
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.loaded = true;
        }
    }
</script>

<style>
    ... removed CSS styles for brevity
</style>
```

Comment: ever tried to use ` waitUntil` to wait a bit for the page loading? Or use SSR to render the page

Comment: Yes I did use waitUntil networkidle2, domcontentloaded, load. Still blank. Have not considered SSR...

Comment: could not reproduce the issue. maybe put a sample project here to reproduce it?